# Create multiple column <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to PrimeFaces and JSF.
i am trying to create  to display multiple columns but i always get a single column from the data in the database. I won't a situation where the drop down (Combo Style) will show multiple columns but one column will set as the value column.

The xhtml portion is shown below. the {investmentProductsController.accountInfo} is a list from my bean. thank you.

```
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{products.CreateInvestmentProductsLabel_totalCostGL}" for="totalCostGL" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="totalCostGL" value="#{investmentProductsController.selected.totalCostGL}" editable="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{products.CreateInvestmentProductsRequiredMessage_totalCostGL}">


                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{investmentProductsController.accountInfo}" var="acc">

                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{acc.accountID}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column >
                                <h:outputText value="#{acc.accountNumber}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column >
                                <h:outputText value="#{acc.accountName}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </f:selectItems>

                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Start by comparing with the PrimeFaces showcase and find the differences http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

The `<p:column>` tags needs to be outside the `<f:selectItems>` tag, so move the `</f:selectItems>` to above the columns.

Comment: and there is more wrong... Hence my reference to the Showcase and people should be able to find basic errors like this themselves